# How to implement a filter without case sensitive using List component of react admin? I mean no diference to filter banada, Banana or BaNana

Tags: list, react-admin, searchbar

Below at my code, I create the component postFilters, that will be used as filters. I want to filter works at my List independent if the world is lowercase or uppercase. I search a lot, but didn't find how to do it use the List component. Anyonde can help me?

I tried to implement the postFilters in the code below, it works partialy.

```
export const MealList = (props: ListProps) => {

  const [searchMeal, setSearchMeal] = useState<string>("");

  const postFilters = [
     <TextInput label="Name" source="nameEn" alwaysOn onChange={(e) => setSearchMeal(e.target.value)} />,
     <TextInput label="Description" source="descriptionEn" />,
    
  ];

  const SimpleData = () => {
    const { data, isLoading } = useListContext();

    const filteredData = data.filter((node) => 
      node.nameEn.toLowerCase().includes(searchMeal.toLowerCase()
    ));
    
    return(
      <Datagrid expand={Details} >
            ...
      </Datagrid>
    );
  }
  return (
    <List {...props} title="Meals List" filters={postFilters}>
      <SimpleData />
    </List>
  ); 
};
```

Comment: Some dataProviders, like `ra-data-postgrest`, support syntaxes like `name@ilike`, but in any cases, it is actually the responsibility of your API, not really react-admin.